# How to give the localhost url in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with javascript and I want to redirect the users to the address of their localhost on port 8661. So when they click on a link, they would see the page redirects to `http://localhost:8661/data.html`. I just simply wrote this address in url but it is not working.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Define "not working."  Does the user *have* a local web server listening on port 8661?  If you entered that address in the browser and the page didn't load then the problem has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: I'm not sure of your question, could you elaborate? If I'm on ```http://ab.cd.com:8661/blah/blah/blah.html```, ```<a href="/data.html">Link</a>``` will direct me to ```http://ab.cd.com:8661/data.html```.

Answer (score 0):

It would only work if there is a local Server that would be sent a request to by Browser. There are many servers like IIS which would read these links and will provide you with the web page if any.

Otherwise you will not get connected to the website (in your case; server) and the Browser would show either a 404 or like Google Chrome it would tell you that the page was not found:

[image]

You need to be using a Server, that would be running and accepting the URL!